# La tournure "Pas eu le temps..." est-elle correcte ?

Tags: usage, registre-familier, régionalismes, anglicismes

Un étudiant a écrit sur sa copie :

> Pas eu le temps de finir, mais il faut juste remplacer x et y par les conditions.

"Pas eu le temps..." me semble incorrect, n'est-ce pas ? Est-ce une tournure régionale ? Est-ce un calque de l'anglais ? Une telle tournure est-elle acceptable sur une copie d'examen (niveau bac+3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est très familier. Si cette proposition est utilisée dans une conversation entre amis (orale ou reproduite par écrit), c'est acceptable. Quand on parle à ses amis, on omet très souvent pas mal de mots. On préfère dire "je sais pas" (chépa) ou "sais pas" au lieu de "Je ne sais pas".

Mais s'il s'agit d'un régistre plus formel, alors il vaut mieux dire

> ***Je n'ai pas eu*** le temps de finir...

Au fait, il y a même une chanson de Patrick Bruel avec ce titre! ["Pas eu le temps"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=dv2Mvb5SIPU&t=0s&list=OLAK5uy_mKhJEc10I7-2-F-6b3ObkuiT1Y2WXGWsc&index=21). Ce n'est pas ma chanson préférée, mais si vous l'écoutez, vous deviendrez plus familier avec l'expression.

Answer (score 3):

C'est la tournure des messages télégraphiés pour lesquels il était important d'économiser les mots.

Si j'étais correcteur je ne m'offusquerais pas de cette forme car l'étudiant manquait manifestement de temps.

Answer (score 0):

Non, ce n'est ni régional ni un anglicisme, c'est bien français et c'est très informel. Non, ce n'est pas du tout acceptable dans les échanges entre professeurs et étudiants.

Il s'agit tout simplement d'une ellipse du sujet, de la particule négative et  du verbe (Je n'ai).